# How do I create a doughnut shape in WorldEdit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit

I'm attempting to recreate the Star Wars Trade Federation ships, and I would like to create a massive doughnut (shape) using WorldEdit. The shape should have a diameter of 147 blocks and thickness of 21 blocks.

How would I go around to doing this in WorldEdit?

Comment: Learn python and write a filter to do it!

Comment: aytimothy made an edit to my question, please take a loot at it!

Answer (score 2):

From the [worldedit wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20190522083153/http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Generation):

> Example: Torus of major radius 0.75 and minor radius 0.25
> //g stone (0.75-sqrt(x^2+y^2))^2+z^2 < 0.25^2

If you'd like to modify the size of the [torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus), substitute the minor and major radiuses for different values.

```
//g -c stone ([Major Radius]-sqrt(x^2+y^2))^2+z^2<[Minor Radius]^2
```

- The **minor radius** is the radius of the inside of the torus.
- The **major radius** is the total radius of the torus.

We also added the "-c" switch in order to create a **regular** torus, where the radius is consistent all around, even if the selection is oddly shaped. This also means that sizes are specified in Minecraft blocks.

---

For your case, you'll want to substitute the major radius with **147** and your minor radius as **147-21**, resulting in:

```
//g -c stone (147-sqrt(x^2+y^2))^2+z^2<(147-21)^2
```

or

```
//g -c stone (147-sqrt(x^2+y^2))^2+z^2<126^2
```

Comment: The //g command using real-block coordinates needs to also have a **-c** option  added.   For more info see my video, which is on generating slanted torus that fits real block dimentions...  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzeNE4gVf70